# Python: setup of logging, allowing multiline strings: logging.info('foo\nbar')

Tags: python, logging

Up to now I do simple logging to files, and if I log a multiline string, then the result looks like this:

Emitting log:

```
logging.info('foo\nbar')
```

Logfile:

```
2018-03-05 10:51:53 root.main +16: INFO     [28302] foo
```

bar

Up to now all lines which do not contain "INFO" or "DEBUG" get reported to operators.

This means the line `bar` gets reported. This is a false positive.

Environment: Linux.

How to set up logging in Python to keep the INFO `foo\nbar` in one string and ignore the whole string since it is only "INFO"?

Note: Yes, you can filter the logging in the interpreter. Unfortunately this is not what the question is about. This question is different. First the logging happens. Then the logs get parsed.

Here is a script to reproduce it:

```
import sys
import logging


def set_up_logging(level=logging.INFO):
    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    root_logger.setLevel(level)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s: %(levelname)-8s [%(process)d] %(message)s', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    root_logger.addHandler(handler)


def main():
    set_up_logging()
    logging.info('foo\nbar')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After thinking about it again, I think the real question is: Which logging format is feasible? Just removing the newlines in messages which span multiple lines makes some output hard to read for the human eyes. On the other hand the current 1:1 relation between logging.info() and a line in the log file is easy to read. ... I am unsure

Comment: Can you show your logging setup line? like `logging.basicConfig(..`, also show what exactly is your desired output with different logging levels?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I added a script to reproduce it. Your question "what exactly is your desired output?" is very good. I have no clue. Up to now we parse the log files and assume that every line is a single log entry. I guess the current pattern is not feasible any more. What is the simplest, sane, most pythonic solution?

Comment: I was thinking (rare for me :)) - what do you use to parse the logs? Maybe is easier and more consistent to enhance that part, especially if you don't want to modify the python sources. For example, in my solution below you might end up with 2 or more alerts none of which contains the full message! (depending on how the parser works). This would need a separate question though...

Comment: You can use `logging.info(json.dumps(message))` which will return a string containing escaped newline characters. Alternatively, you can create a custom `Formatter` class that does this automatically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I usually have a class to customize logging but you can achieve what you want with a custom `logging.Formatter`:

```
import logging

class NewLineFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def __init__(self, fmt, datefmt=None):
        """
        Init given the log line format and date format
        """
        logging.Formatter.__init__(self, fmt, datefmt)


    def format(self, record):
        """
        Override format function
        """
        msg = logging.Formatter.format(self, record)

        if record.message != "":
            parts = msg.split(record.message)
            msg = msg.replace('\n', '\n' + parts[0])

        return msg
```

The `format()` function above splits lines and replicates the timestamp/logging-preamble in each line (after every `\n`)

Now you need to attach the formatter to the root logger. You can actually attach it to any `handler` if you build your own logging setup/structure:

```
# Basic config as usual
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Some globals/consts
DATEFORMAT = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
LOGFORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(process)s %(levelname)-8s %(filename)15s-%(lineno)-4s: %(message)s'

# Create a new formatter
formatter = NewLineFormatter(LOGFORMAT, datefmt=DATEFORMAT)

# Attach the formatter on the root logger
lg = logging.getLogger()

# This is a bit of a hack... might be a better way to do this
lg.handlers[0].setFormatter(formatter)


# test root logger
lg.debug("Hello\nWorld")

# test module logger + JSON
lg = logging.getLogger("mylogger")
lg.debug('{\n    "a": "Hello",\n    "b": "World2"\n}')
```

The above gives you:

```
05-03-2018 08:37:34 13065 DEBUG     test_logger.py-47  : Hello
05-03-2018 08:37:34 13065 DEBUG     test_logger.py-47  : World
05-03-2018 08:37:34 13065 DEBUG     test_logger.py-51  : {
05-03-2018 08:37:34 13065 DEBUG     test_logger.py-51  :     "a": "Hello",
05-03-2018 08:37:34 13065 DEBUG     test_logger.py-51  :     "b": "World2"
05-03-2018 08:37:34 13065 DEBUG     test_logger.py-51  : }
```

Note that I am accessing the `.handlers[0]` of the root logger which is a bit of a hack but I couldn't find a way around this... Also, note the formatted JSON printing :)

Comment: I hoped this question could be solved by configuring. But it seems that you need to do programming .... But of course your answer is much better than no solution :-)

Comment: I see... The above code/solution is from 3 years back! so in this time `logging` might have introduced a better way of doing this. However, back then I could not find anything out there.

Comment: It will be much easier with 3rd party [structlog](https://structlog.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and its processors stack.

Comment: This doesn't work if the log call internally has interpolation in it on subsequent lines

Answer (score 3):

I think maintaining this 1:1 relationship, a single line in the log file for each `logging.info()` call, is highly desirable to keep the log files simple and parsable. Therefore, if you really need to log a newline character, then I would simply log the *string representation* instead, for example:

```
logging.info(repr('foo\nbar'))
```

Outputs:

```
2018-03-05 11:34:54 root: INFO     [32418] 'foo\nbar'
```

A simple alternative would be to log each part separately:

```
log_string = 'foo\nbar'
for item in log_string.split('\n'):
    logging.info(item)
```

Outputs:

```
2018-03-05 15:39:44 root: INFO     [4196] foo
2018-03-05 15:39:44 root: INFO     [4196] bar
```

Comment: I am unsure. I use Linux since 1996 and like the simple ascii based solutions a lot. But maybe it is time to switch here? This 1:1 relationship exists since ages. What could be used instead of it? Things can get unreadable if you just remove the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=your_level)
```

where your_level is one of those:

```
  'debug': logging.DEBUG,
  'info': logging.INFO,
  'warning': logging.WARNING,
  'error': logging.ERROR,
  'critical': logging.CRITICAL
```

In your case, you can use warning to ignore info

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.WARNING)

logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')

Output:
WARNING:root:And this, too
```

You can try disabling INFO Prior to logging as

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log')

logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.disable(logging.INFO)
logging.info('So should this')
logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)
logging.warning('And this, too')
Output:
WARNING:root:And this, too
```

Or

```
logger.disabled = True
someOtherModule.function()
logger.disabled = False
```

Comment: Yes, you can filter the logging in the interpreter. Unfortunately this is not what the question is about. This question is different. First the logging happens. Then the logs get parsed.

Comment: @guettli I have edited my answer so that you may disable INFO prior to log generation.

Comment: I want INFO to be in the log files. This question is about the parsing/reading/analyzing of the log files.